# Rolle's theorem and concav/convex function

Tags: real-analysis

Let’s say we have $g(x)=(1+x)e^{-x}$

1) *Can we say that the function is concav ? convex ? neither convex nor concav ?*

This is the wording of the exam.

$g''(x)=(x-1)e^{-x}$

So, normally, we can tell that $g(x)$ is concav between $\left[-\infty;1 \right]$ and convex elsethere.

**The fact that it is not concav everywhere, does it mean that we can tell that it is neither convex nor concav ?**

2) $g(x)=0$ has a unique solution. *True or false ?*

We know that there exists at least one solution, which is -1.
We know that this should be the only solution as the exponentiel does not vanish.

**By Rolle’s Theorem**, there exists more than one solution if $g’(x)$ has a root.
Since $g'(x)=-xe^{-x}$ has a root, which is $0$, we can say there are more than one solution.

**Can somebody help to use Rolle's theorem to prove that there is at most 1 solution to $g(x)=0$ ?**

Addition:
Can we use the Rolle's theorem here ? I am not so sure, given that the question does not refer to a closed interval ?

Edit: I rephrased the question of 2)

Comment: Rolle's theorem guarantees a zero of $g'$, given two zeros of $g$, whereas you are trying to stipulate the converse, which is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) is correct.

For 2) use the fact  $ab=0\iff (a=0)\lor( b=0)$ and that the exponential function doesn't vanish.

Comment: Sorry, but that does not answer the question of uniqueness of solution that I am referring to. I know there is one solution, but I want to know if there is another solution(s).

Comment: Hi Sami. Have a great hours ahead. :)